# "A sensible person like you" vs. "a sensible person like yourself"

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, reflexives

What is the difference between *you* and *yourself* in the following context?

> - My dear Professor, surely a sensible person like *yourself* can call him by his name.
> - My dear Professor, surely a sensible person like *you* can call him by his name.

Comment: I feel like "you" is a more personal term, and "yourself" is more like a straightfoward term.

Comment: Hmm..I think "you" sounds more straightforward, and "yourself" sounds like the speaker is trying to be fancy. I get annoyed at the overuse of "self".  For example, I often hear sentences such as: "The man gave apples to Ann and myself."  Why not just say "me"?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/600425/2085).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both are grammatical. Pronouns like *yourself* are reflexive pronouns and they have two main uses. One is to ‘reflect’ the action described in the verb back onto the subject, as in ‘I hurt myself’. The other is to emphasise the doer or the recipient of an action, as in ‘I did it myself’. In your example, *yourself* is used slightly differently in that it’s preceded by a preposition. The effect is to draw greater attention to what the professor, as a sensible person, might be permitted to do.

Comment: This looks like an [untriggered reflexive](http://arnoldzwicky.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/viewpoint-reflexive/).

Answer (score 1):

The reflexive pronoun *yourself* is the marked form here. To me it suggests that the speaker believes it shows a little more deference than the unmarked *you*.

And surely you mean *surely* not *surly*!

Comment: What does it mean to say that something is the "marked" form here?

Comment: @aparente001. From the entry on _marked_ in _The Oxford Concise Dictionary of Linguistics_ (p236): In general, of any unit, construction, etc. which is in any way a special case, which is more complex or is subject to more restrictions, which is perceived as unusual, or which is simply rarer.

Comment: Can you boil it down for me?  I will make a stab.  Are you saying *The reflexive pronoun "yourself" is a special case*?

Comment: @aparente001. Garner, in _Modern American Usage_ in the entry on reflexive pronouns (p466) states: _The key to the use of reflexive pronouns is that each one should reflect an antecent. They are misused when they just stand in for personal pronouns._ And _Merriam Webster's Dictionary of English Usage_ (p971) in the entry on _yourself_ says: _The use of the reflexive yourself in constructions where they are not reflexive or intensive has been criticized since at least the time of MacCracken & Sandison, 1917_.

Comment: A further definition of _markedness_ is provided by Peters in _The Cambridge Dictionary of English Grammar_: _Marked forms are usually relatively uncommon by comparison with their unmarked counterparts. ... This notion of markedness is more debatable than the first, because it relates to more abstract linguistic properties, and to relative frequencies which may be difficult to establish with any certainty_. By the above definition, the reflexive pronoun can be considered marked in such a context as the OP's.

Answer (score -1):

The Use of youself if more appropriate in that you are describing the qualities of a person. "Yourself" is generally used when you are implying possession. In your example sentence, the person's possession here is the quality or character of sensibility. USe Yourself after your decribe someone or after you state the someone's possession.