# Which is correct?

Tags: word-choice, pronouns, reflexives

Which is correct?

> Dear Jay, I was contacted by Sue on behalf of herself, John, and you.

or

> Dear Jay, I was contacted by Sue on behalf of herself, John, and yourself.

Comment: Check out the 2nd answer [here][1]
  [1]: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/when-is-it-correct-to-use-yourself-and-myself-versus-you-and-me

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27101/people-like-you-versus-people-like-yourself and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69999/a-sensible-person-like-you-vs-a-sensible-person-like-yourself

Comment: And http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10684/if-you-are-talking-on-behalf-of-you-and-someone-else-what-is-the-correct-usag, which is specifically about "on behalf of"

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest?

**Dear Jay, I have been contacted by Sue on John's and your behalf...**

or

**Dear Jay, Sue has contacted me on John's and your behalf...**